# How to find the maximum of this oscillating function?

Tags: optimization, greens-function

Given $n \in\mathbb{N}$, $a_1, \dots, a_n \in\mathbb{C}$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1, \dots x_n \in \mathbb{R}^3$, let $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb C$ be defined by

$$\Phi (y) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i \frac{e^{j k \| x_i - y \|_2}}{\| x_i - y \|_2}}$$

where $j := \sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit. Note the singularities at $y \in \{ x_1, \dots x_n \}$.

Can somebody please point me to a more elegant method than brute forcing (just evaluating the expression at millions of points) to find $y$ for which $|\Phi|$ has the global maximum and is not near a singularity (distance > $k$)?

Comment: I understand that $\| x \|^2$ is the square of $\| x \|$, but what's the meaning of $\| x \| _2$?

Comment: $\| x - y \|_2$ is the L2-Norm (the euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$)

Comment: So $\| x - y \|_2$ is the same as the "regular" $\| x - y \|$ :-)

Comment: I wonder if there is some insight to be gained from the physics you're interested in solving here. Clearly this looks like a potential of a collection of time-harmonic charges, but I can't get my head around why you would want to maximize the potential. My intuition says away from the sources there will be one or more dominant lines along which things will add up constructively (analogous to the peaks in an antenna pattern), and then you can simply do a gradient-based optimization after restricting y to each of those lines. But I of course have not worked out the details.

Comment: You are right on the point. Note that im looking for the point where the sum of a given number of time-harmonic charges in space with a given amplitude and phase has its global maximum. I think (linear) gradient-based optimization doesnt work, since there are many local minima and maxima in the field since the fundamental solution of the Helmholtz-Equation is used here and theres alot of oscillation going on.

Comment: Also I think your "not near a singularity" condition should be distance>1/k since k necessarily has inverse-distance as its unit, and distance > 2pi/k is maybe even better so you're at least one wavelength away from the singularity

Comment: Is a result that is valid for y very far away from the charges acceptable, or are you specifically looking for the maximal potential in the near-field of the charges?

Comment: Yeah true using the wavelength 2pi/k could be a better condition. Im looking for y with a minimum distance of about a wavelength from the charge but I would be happy with any result you have obtained be it nearfield or farfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which implements a maximization procedure to obtain the desired maximum. The nature of the problem, prone to many relative maxima, indicates to choose an evolutionary algorithm to perform the search. The charge points are given in `X` the coefficients $a_k$ are given as `a[1],...,a[n]`, $k$ is represented by `lambda`. The objective function is handled as $\|\Phi(y)\|^2$ and the unknown $y$ as `Y`. Attached a plot showing in blue the `X` charge points and in red the solution for `Y`.

```
SeedRandom[2]
Clear[Phi]
n = 30;
r = 0.06;
parms = Join[Table[a[k] -> 1, {k, 1, n}], {lambda -> 5}];
X = RandomReal[2 {-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
Y = {x, y, z};
dots = Table[Sqrt[(X[[k]] - Y).(X[[k]] - Y)], {k, 1, n}];
Phi[j_] := Sum[a[k] Exp[j lambda dots[[k]]]/dots[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
objr = (Phi[I] + Phi[-I])/2 // ComplexExpand;
obji = (Phi[I] - Phi[-I])/(I 2) // ComplexExpand;
obj = objr^2 + obji^2;
restrs = Table[Sqrt[(X[[k]] - Y).(X[[k]] - Y)] - 2 Pi/lambda, {k, 1, n}];
restrs0 = Thread[restrs > 0];
case = Join[{obj}, restrs0] /. parms;
sol = Quiet@NMaximize[case, Y, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(******* To show the fitting to the restrictions *******)
restrs /. parms /. sol[[2]]
restrs0 = Thread[restrs > 0] /. parms /. sol[[2]]
(*******************************************************)

gr1 = Table[Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[X[[k]], r]}], {k, 1, n}];
gr2 = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[Y, r]} /. sol[[2]]];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]